# Good compact antenna for FM audio transmitter module?

Tags: antenna, transmitter, frequency-modulation

I've been looking at building a short range FM transmitter using [this](http://www.seeedstudio.com/depot/pll-fm88108mhz-stereo-audio-transmitter-module-p-1133.html?cPath=139) module, the idea is to create a small module that I can integrate into other projects. I'd prefer having the antenna on the same PCB using a trace or chip antenna, would this be reliable considering the low power output of the unit? (I'm hoping to get at least a 20m range)

[image]

If so I'd appreciate any suggestions for this antenna.